# c++ curl download image and save in gdi+ Image object

Tags: c++, winapi, libcurl, gdi+

I have a code that downloads an image and saves it in file:

```
void saveImage(string url) {
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    FILE* file = fopen("img.png", "wb");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, save_image);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, file);

    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    fclose(data);
}
size_t save_image(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE* file) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, data);
    return written;
}
```

Then I load the image from this file and draw it:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    Graphics gf(hdc);
    Image img(L"img.png");
    gf.DrawImage(&img, 10, 10);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
```

I want to download image and load it directly in `Image` object without saving it in file, something like this:

```
void getImage(string url, Image &img) {
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, load_image);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, img);

    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
size_t load_image(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, Image &img) {
    //load the downloaded image in img
}
```

I'm not sure the `getImage` function is right but this is just an example how I want it to work.

I found an example of how to load image from BYTE array and wrote this code:

```
void getImage(string url, Image *&img) {
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, load_image);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, img);

    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
size_t load_image(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, Image *&img) {
    IStream* stream = ::SHCreateMemStream((BYTE*)ptr, size);
    img = Image::FromStream(stream);
    return size * nmemb;
}
...
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (wp) {
        case onButtonClicked:
        getImage(url, img);
        draw = true;
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
        break;
    }
    break;
case WM_PAINT:
{
    if (draw) {
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        Graphics gf(hdc);
        gf.DrawImage(img, 10, 50);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
}
```

But when I click the button the app crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution. Instead of curl I used URLOpenBlockingStream:

```
IStream* stream;
...
case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wp) {
        case onButtonClicked:
            draw = true;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            break;
        }
        break;
case WM_PAINT:
        if (draw) {
            URLOpenBlockingStreamA(0, url, &stream, 0, 0);
            Bitmap* bmp = Bitmap::FromStream(stream);
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            Graphics gf(hdc);
            gf.DrawImage(bmp, 10, 50);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
```